# Vim -p: Caught deadly signal SEGV?

Tags: crash

I get this problem when I start Vim with `-p` option. Suppose, I started out with

```
vim -p first.txt second.txt
```

Then after editing `first.txt` I move to `second.txt` using `gt`. I press the keys `gg` and `G` again. This produces the error

```
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
```

From this point, Vim doesn't respond to any signal including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>. I can close this session only by killing the terminal.

This problem arises only when I invoke Vim with `-p` option. If I open `first.txt` first and then use `:tabe` to open `second.txt`, this problem doesn't arise.

Any ideas why this might occur?

---

Output of `vim --version`:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:40:46)
Included patches: 1-52
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version with GTK2-GNOME GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
+balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
+browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui  +lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           +xsmp_interact
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    +xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz   -pthread -DORBIT2=1 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/libgnomeui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libart-2.0 -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1 -I/usr/include/libgnome-2.0 -I/usr/include/libbonoboui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnomecanvas-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/orbit-2.0 -I/usr/include/libbonobo-2.0 -I/usr/include/bonobo-activation-2.0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gail-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12     -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/usr/include/tcl8.6  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1  
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfreetype     -lgnomeui-2 -lSM -lICE -lbonoboui-2 -lgnomevfs-2 -lgnomecanvas-2 -lgnome-2 -lpopt -lbonobo-2 -lbonobo-activation -lORBit-2 -lart_lgpl_2 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lgconf-2 -lgthread-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0   -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua5.2 -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl/5.18/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lcrypt -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-i386-linux-gnu -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions  -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -ltcl8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lieee -lm -lruby-1.9.1 -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm  -L/usr/lib
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux nitish 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:37:48 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Based on comments by @Carpetsmoker, I found out that the problem is because of my `.vimrc` file. So I checked ran the problem causing command with some portions of the `.vimrc` file commented. Finally I found out that the problem is with the line

```
set columns=1000
```

How can so innocent command cause this problem? `:help columns` didn't give any useful information regarding this.

Comment: which vim (and patch level) are you using? (like vim --version output), and what OS? Regardless, it would be a good idea to update vim. If you're on a Mac and you use ruby plugins (like command-T), you might reinstall them and/or make sure vim is using system ruby and not rvm ruby (which seems to have caused troubles for some people)

Comment: You can start vim as `vim -u NONE -p first.txt second.txt` ... This will prevent loading your vimrc file.

Comment: @hatter The vim was installed or compiled? Can you upgrade it to 7.4 and see if that helps.

Comment: @kenorb Vim was installed.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It worked!! Does this definitively point that there is a problem in `.vimrc` file?

Comment: @hatter It would seem so; perhaps this problem is only triggered if a certain section is enabled, or perhaps a certain plugin ... you could try to comment out lines (or blocks of lines), see if the problem still occurs, and repeat until it doesn't ... That way you can find out where the problem is...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker please see the edited question.

Comment: @hatter You should dump the core file and check the backtrace with `gdb` what exactly is happening. If no symbols are visible, then probably you need to install vim with debug symbols or re-compile it.

Comment: @kenorb Vim doesn't write to a core file. When this problem occurs, I kill the terminal. I think this closes Vim before it can write to the core file.

Comment: @hatter All programs normally write to core file on SEGV, but sometimes these needs to be enabled depending on the OS. If it's Linux, [see](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31187/21471).

Comment: did you ever end up filing a bug report? If so, let me know so that I can add my information there too since I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @AlexanderBird No. I didn't. I tried to get it write to the core file but couldn't. I gave up there :/.

Answer (score 6):

The SEGV signal, also known as a segfault, is almost always due to a bug in the program you're running—in this case, vim. (Other causes are things like defective hardware, or once in a blue moon, kernel bugs).

So, really, you need to report a bug. [`:help bug-reports`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#bug-reports) provides instructions on how to report a bug. It sounds like you've already got a minimal set of steps to reproduce the problem, so that's most of the work there. You should probably test a newer version of Vim first though, just to make sure it hasn't already been fixed.

Comment: I am using Vim 7.4. Official website says this is the latest version.

Comment: @hatter you have fewer patches applied than are available.

Comment: He's running Debian, so that explains that :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I'm running Debian and have through patch 488... I'm not sure why OP has older. Wheezy (current release) has 7.3, so OP isn't using that. Unstable, Jessie, and Wheezy-Backports all have 7.4 patch 488. (Given, 640 is current, so that's still somewhat old.)

Answer (score 4):

If your vim crashes because of [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), that indicates memory access violation which is caused either by software bug or hardware issues.

If this happens repeatedly, you should do in order:

1. Disable plugins by running: `vim -u NONE` and see if that helps.
2. Upgrade your vim to the latest stable version.
3. Upgrade your vim to the latest development version.
4. Optionally double check the same vim version on different machine (maybe it's caused by hardware issues).
5. Try to run `vim` under debugger, e.g.: `gdb vim` and check for the backtrace (after SEGV, in `gdb`: type `bt` or `bt full`).
6. If the backtrace doesn't have symbols, you've to recompile your vim to include these.
7. If you've complete backtrace, please check for similar issues or report a new bug in [vim's bug tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues) (for plain vim) or check for `:help bugs`. If you've different version of vim (like gVim, MacVim, NeoVim), please report it to the right maintainers.

Comment: This happens only on my system. Doesn't happen with `-u NONE`. Seems the line `set columns=1000` in `.vimrc` is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation faults may also be connected to interacting servers like netbeans and an `autocmd` that invalidates a buffer (e.g. `BufNewFile` operations) that another program (plugin, ...) expects (or similar) in the `.vim` configuration, try commenting those lines in e.g. the `.vimrc`.

Typical error message is:

```
missing ! or / in <number>:<command>
```

where
`command` can be e.g. `editFile`